# можно ли перекомпилировать приложение Android с версии 4.0 в 2.3?

Tags: android

Я написал приложение, при создании проекта я выбрал вырсию прошивки 4.0 (ice cream sandwich, Api level 15) , но на устройствах android 2.2 (api level 8) оно не запускается!
Вопрос:  можно ли не переписывая приложение скомпилировать его под api level 8 ? И если - нет,  то какие остаются варианты?

P.S. в проекте использовались

- IntentService (с BroadcastReceiver )
- AsyncTask
- SQLite

Comment: все зависит от того, как писался код. Но есть подозрение, что ответ скорее всего будет "вряд ли".

Но судя по статистике, я бы на level 8 даже не смотрел. Нет смысла.

Comment: Боже мой. 2016 год почти, хватит поддерживать это старьё, пожалуйста.

Comment: Да,я  понимаю, по-этому изначально и начал писать для минимум 4.0,
тут просто момент принципиальный. И все же, что в таком случае можно сделать?

Comment: Если есть исходники, понижать в манифесте minSDKlevel до 8 и смотреть, что перестало работать(IDE сразу укажет на невозможность использовать определенные классы) и можно ли чем-нибудь заменить/накостылить.

Comment: Автору на будущее, если уж трындец как нужна поддержка старых версий, то юзайте support labrary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всё, что вы назвали поддерживается даже 4 версией API, поэтому должно пойти, что по поводу того, что не запускается, то это может быть банально из-за флага минимальной версии в манифесте, возможно там стоит цифра больше 8, поэтому и кидает ошибку, хотя потенциально работать должно.